# (How) can I use AnimationDrawables in an Android Widget?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-widget

I have an Android Widget which contains multiple ImageViews. In the `onUpdate` I use `setImageViewResource` to apply an animated drawable (which I defined in an XML file in the `drawable` folder) to the ImageViews.

My problem is that the animations don't play automatically once they are displayed, and I have no way to access the `ImageView` directly or the `AnimationDrawable` to call `start()` on it.

So my question, is it even possible to have animated Drawables in a widget and if yes, how can I do it?